# docker получить ip от dhcp и присвоить его контейнеру для использования в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, docker, docker-compose

Я через docker-compose подымаю несколько контейнеров из [этой](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) репы и заворачиваю свой код. Контейнеры и сайт работают.

Встал вопрос о том чтобы контейнерам назначить адрес в сети (IP) и чтобы по данному адресу мог любой компютер в сети зайти.

По данной проблеме более менее вменяемые ответы нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539727/giving-a-docker-container-a-routable-ip-address), но они предполагают прямое указание какой IP нужно выдать.(после выдачи сайт стает доступный по этому IP).

Сейчас работаю над оптимизацией и встал вопрос:
Как можно в от DHCP получить любой свободный IP, и его как то применить при запуске?

Comment: при старте вы хотите назначить контейнеру адрес полученный по dhcp?

Comment: docker-контейнеры (без дополнительных плагинов сети) не могут работать иначе как используя сеть хоста или внутреннюю приватную сеть. Для того, чтобы выдать айпишник на интерфейс, его нужно сначала создать на машине-хосте, а это не очень хорошо укладывается в общие концепции докера (который подразумевает, что все вещи происходят изолированно от хоста). Используйте fronten proxy, который будет висеть в тех же внутренних сетях и получать конечный адрес через dns.